# How to efficiently generate random signs/{-1,1} in matlab?

Tags: performance, matlab, random, sign

In Matlab, I need to generate signs (i.e. {-1,1}) randomly. I've come out with a solution, but I need this to be lighter. My solution implies calling two functions, a multiplication (although it's a binary shift) and a subtraction.

This is my code:

```
L=1000;
x=2*round(rand(L,1))-1;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the following to get `+1` when the random number is greater than `0.5` and `-1` otherwise:

```
(rand(L,1) > 0.5)*2 - 1
```

Or similar with `randi`:

```
randi([0,1], L, 1)*2 - 1
```